# Seating arrangement of couples

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to seat $10$ people consisting of $5$ couples in a row of 10 seats, if all couple are to get adjacent seats.

I proceeded by creating five- 2 block partitions of the $10$ seats by $\frac{10!}{2!^5*5!}$ and then distributing these partitions of $2$ seats each to $5$ couples in 5! ways accounting to $\frac{10!}{2!^5}=113400$ but it came to be incorrect.

Where I went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First fill $10$ slots (seats) left to right keeping in mind the restriction that
couples have to sit together. There are $10$ choices for the first slot (no restriction),$ 1$ choice for the second (since the first person’s mate has to be seated there), $8$ choices for the third slot (since $2$ people have now been seated, leaving $8$), $1$ choice for the fourth slot (since this seat has to go to the mate #$3$)

So, there are $10\times8\times6\times4\times2=3840$ ways

Comment: I got this approach. But please please tell me why my approach failed? What I overcounted?

Comment: what is incorrect in my approach? i just arranged them as a group of 2,and seated...do we need to arrange seats as well?

Comment: @omega read my full answer and you will understand where you went wrong.

Comment: does second person always seats on right of first person in a couple?

Comment: hence only 1 choice...

Comment: @omega In first stage Select someone to sit in the 1st chair 
There are 10 people to choose from, so we can complete stage 1 in 10 ways. In second stage, Select someone to sit in the 2nd chair 
The person seated in the 2nd chair must be the partner of the person in the 1st chair 
So we can complete this stage in 1 way.

Comment: and then his partner in 2nd...then 8 people for 3rd seat...

Comment: @omega yes, and so on till 10th seat and we get $(10)(1)(8)(1)(6)(1)(4)(1)(2)(1)$
 ways

Comment: ok...got this one, but how can i rectify my approach?